# Specifying a range when accessing array keys in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, key, range

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
a_function_here($string[0...5]);
```

instead of:

```
a_function_here($string[0], $string[1], $string[2], $string[3], $string[4], $string[5]);
```

I have never used any such function and I have searched everywhere for some reference to this but I haven't been able to encounter anything about this.

Comment: Can you show an example of *real world usage*? With *real* data in the array, and a *real* function instead of `a_function_here`. I believe you are looking for something like "slice/apply", but a *real example* would clarify this.

Comment: Was this problem solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass an array of arguments to a known function with [`call_user_func_array`](https://www.php.net/call_user_func_array) ***e.g.***

```
call_user_func_array('a_function_here', array_slice($string, 0, 6));
```

[**demo**](http://ideone.com/llMBE9)

Answer (score 0):

There's no need of a special syntax `$string[0...5]`. You're simply trying to pass a number of elements of the array `$string` to the function, so you can just do:

```
a_function_here($stringArr);
```

And inside the function, you can do:

```
function a_function_here(array $stringArr) {
    foreach ($stringArr as $str) {
        # function logic here ...
    }
    ...
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Passing the array doesn't work for existing functions taking in different parameters, as the OP presented.

Comment: @user2864740: Can't you just modify the function?